# 13.04 Freezing (New install, with nothing installed yet e.g. drivers)

Tags: ati, freeze, 13.04

Ubuntu 13.04 keeps freezing on the desktop, it doesn't matter what I'm doing it just freezes, the cursor still works but no other input e.g. keyboard. This is with a clean install, I haven't even installed drivers yet. It did last long enough to install the AMD drivers (13.3 beta 3) once but froze after the drivers had finished installing but before I could reboot, so I had to reboot and then X wouldn't start. I log in and there's no GUI, ALT-CTRL-DEL to logout and try the Guest account and still no interface.